# Migrate data from database on MarkLogic 7 to database on MarkLogic 9

Tags: upgrade, data-migration, marklogic-9, marklogic-7

I need to copy data from a MarkLogic 7 database to MarkLogic 9 database on another system. I tried backup and restore option provided by the MarkLogic Admin console. The original database in MarkLogic 7 had only 1 forest attached to it. I created a new database with the same name in MarkLogic 9. Also created a new forest in MarkLogic 9 with the same name as in MarkLogic 7 attached to it. I am not sure where i am doing it wrong.

**Steps followed in detail:**

1. Go to MarkLogic 7 Admin console.
2. Go to Configure -> Databases -> `<database_name>` -> Backup/Restore
   tab
3. Enter the path to store the backup.
4. Select 'true' for Include replica forests.
5. Select 'false' for Archive journals.
6. Click 'OK' button.
7. Go to MarkLogic 9 Admin console.
8. Go to Configure -> Databases -> `<database_name>` -> Backup/Restore
   tab
9. Enter the path to restore the backup from.
10. Select 'true' for Include replica forests.
11. Select default values for other radio buttons.
12. Click 'OK' button.
13. I receive the following error:

Operation failed with error message:XDMP-BACKUPEMPTY: xdmp:database-restore((), "", (), fn:false(), (), fn:false(), (),"") -- No forests specified for backup or restore.. Check server logs.

Comment: Try setting `forest topology changed` to true.  It should allow you to see which forests are contained in the backup, and where those forests should be restored.

Comment: Also, just to verify...you are going from ML 7 on RHEL/CENTOS 6 to ML 9 on RHEL/CENTOS 7?

Comment: Thanks @MichaelGardner. Setting the `forest topology changed` to true did the trick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While restoring the backup selecting the `forest topology changed` to true worked for me. Thanks [Michael Gardner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1630893/michael-gardner) for the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56577959/migrate-data-from-database-on-marklogic-7-to-database-on-marklogic-9#comment99783820_56577959).

[Refer this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4nx9Q.png)